# Getting "function not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick" error for unknown reasons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have defined a button in JavaScript like this:

```
function MyFunction(){
    $.post("servletname", {"element": variable}, function(data){
       var action = document.createElement("a");
       action.setAttribute("class", "button")
       action.setAttribute("onclick", "doSomething(" + data + ")");
       action.appendChild(randomNode);
    })
}
```

Then in the same code, outside `MyFunction`, I have defined the function `doSomething` like:

```
function doSomething(dataFromJQuery){
   //do things with dataFromJQuery
}
```

The function `MyFunction()` is invoked somewhere earlier in the code, while of course the function `doSomething` should be invoked when the button is clicked.

But every time I click the button, I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

and `doSomething` doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong with the code structure or is it just a syntax error somewhere? What does the error message mean?

Comment: `doSomething` would have to be global if used from an attribute event handler. Also, you could use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems to work to me:

```js
var action = document.createElement("a");
action.setAttribute("class", "button")
action.setAttribute("onclick", "doSomething('data')");
action.innerText = 'Action'
document.body.appendChild(action)

function doSomething(dataFromJQuery){
   console.log(dataFromJQuery)
}
```

Granted, I had to modify your code a bit so that it would work in the snippet. But the `onclick` does correctly trigger.

In other words, I don't see anything wrong, we'll probably need to see the rest of your code.

You could also try `addEventListener`:

```
var action = document.createElement('a')
action.setAttribute('class', 'button')
action.addEventListener('click', () => doSomething(data))
```

Notice the anonymous (arrow) function, which allows us to pass `data` to `doSomething` without calling the function right away.

Comment: @Ele the `doSomething` function is wrapped in a closure so it won't be called until the event is fired. I wrapped it like that so it could be given the `data` argument (which isn't defined in my small example) without being immediately called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the passed param `data` which is probably a string.

An alternative is wrapping with sigle quote `'`

```js
function addLink(data) {
  var action = document.createElement("a");
  action.setAttribute("class", "button")
  action.setAttribute("href", "#")
  action.setAttribute("onclick", "doSomething('" + data + "')");
  action.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click me!!"));
  
  //action.appendChild(randomNode);
  
  document.body.appendChild(action);
}

function doSomething(dataFromJQuery) {
  console.log(dataFromJQuery)
}

addLink("Hello from Ele!");
```

Adopt the function `addEventListener` to bind events to the elements:

```js
function addLink(data) {
  var action = document.createElement("a");
  action.setAttribute("class", "button");
  action.setAttribute("href", "#");

  action.addEventListener('click', function() {
    doSomething(data);
  });

  action.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click me!!"));

  //action.appendChild(randomNode);

  document.body.appendChild(action);
}

function doSomething(dataFromJQuery) {
  console.log(dataFromJQuery)
}

addLink("Hello from Ele!");
```